# Why do I get a NullpointerException when invoking the CXF-RS endpoint of a Camel route?

Tags: java, integration, cxf, apache-camel, cxfrs

My app is an java webapp (WAR) that uses Apache Camel and (among others) CXF-RS and its corresponding Camel component as an implementation of JAX-RS to provide ReSTful services to the outside world.

When invoking one of the endpoints with an HTTP POST and a valid payload I get the Exception stack trace as you can see below. Note that the com.foo.FooService and com.foo.Foo classes are a JAXRS annotated service/resource pair.

I'm especially confused that the create() method is actually getting invoked as it was my understanding that CXF-RS for Camel somehow performs some magic to intercept incoming requests and to route the request into a Camel route.

These are simplified versions of the classes:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
public class Foo implements Serializable {
// some getters and setters go here
}


@Path("/")
public class FooService {

    public FooService() {
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/foos")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public Response create(Foo foo) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

I configure the cxf:rsServer as follows in my Spring XML:

```
<cxf:rsServer id="fooServer" serviceClass="com.foo.FooService" address="/foorest"/>
```

The route is defined in Java as follows:

```
from("cxfrs://bean://fooServer").id("foo-restadapter-route")
    .to("jms:queue:foos").inOnly();
```

Here is the exception as I get it:

```
SEVERE: Error occurred during error handling, give up!
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: null while invoking public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.foo.FooService.create(com.foo.Foo) with params [com.foo.Foo@1ed43997].
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:159)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:133)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:133)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:82)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:110)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:98)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:423)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:139)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:142)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsInvoker.getContinuation(CxfRsInvoker.java:63)
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsInvoker.performInvocation(CxfRsInvoker.java:52)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:89)
        ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3343) of `camel-cxf`, you can workaround this issue by changing the route like this

```
from("cxfrs://bean://fooServer?synchronous=true").id("foo-restadapter-route")
.to("jms:queue:foos").inOnly();
```

Comment: Yes, I actually went into the source code, figured it out and filed that bug with Camel mysel. ;) But thanks for the workaround as well, did not know you could force synchronous requests like this.

Comment: The given URL no longer works: It has been moved to : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3343